# What happened if I install two version of ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because I found that the latest version of ROS is coming(electric).

If I want to try that version,but also use the origin version of ROS.

Is they will conflict?

Or should I just upgrade to the latest version?

I have tried 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'.
Is this instruction will check any version of ROS could be update? And if not,it just upgrade all the other packages?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10660/what-happened-if-i-install-two-version-of-ros?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS installations won't interfere with each other, if using the precompiled .deb packages or installing from source into different directories. E.g. diamondback will install into /opt/ros/diamondback, whereas electric will install into /opt/ros/e-turtle (or "electric", whatever the actual directory will be). Once you source one "setup.bash" you will run (and compile) in that ROS version only.

So, apt-get dist-upgrade will not upgrade your ROS installation into a new distribution as the package prefixes are different.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-20**:
Yes. Your code might not be compatible to both, though.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
If I want to change versions,I just run the correct setup.bash file without other steps,right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend you to continue learning with the current diamondback release and don't change until electric is stable.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle you can have multiple versions installed at the same time and this will work, as long as you take care that you only use one version (and packages for that version) at any time. This means the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, setup.bash and everything else of only the ROS version you want to use might be active. Making a mistake here can lead to all sorts of errors.
It's recommended to use only one version (a stable one) though, unless you have special needs.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-07-20**:
For example having a PACKAGE_PATH that accidentally contains packages for another distribution than the one you have defined in your setup.bash file.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
What kind of mistake will lead to all sorts of errors? Thank you~